# Flasgger header parameters aren't described

Tags: python, api, flask, swagger, flasgger

I try to implement swagger documentation for the project using flasgger. When I describe body fields - it works ok, but when I try to describe header fields, flasgger doesn't present the description of the parameters on the web.

An example of .yml file for flasgger.

```
description: Client side interaction with server
consumes:
- "application/json"
parameters:
  - in: header
    name: headers_params
    required: true
    schema:
      id: endpoint_header
      required:
        - session_token
      properties:
        session_token:
          type: string
          description: session token
  - in: body
    name: body_params
    required: true
    schema:
      id: endpoint_body
      required:
        - parameter1
        - parameter2
      properties:
        parameter1:
          type: string
          description: The parameter1 description
        parameter2:
          type: string
          description: The parameter2 description

responses:
  500:
      description: The error on the server side

  200:
      description: Access token for user intercation
```

And, its what I see on web:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6RcD.png)

What structure of .yml file should I follow to get the session token described in the header as well as body parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using OpenAPI 2.0 syntax. In OAS2, [header parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/#header-parameters) are described like this:

```yaml
  - in: header
    name: session_token    # <---- HTTP header name
    required: true
    type: string
    description: session token
```

Alternatively, authentication-related headers such as session tokens can be described as a [security scheme](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/), e.g. as an [API key](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/).

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

securityDefinitions:
  session_token:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: session_token   # <---- HTTP header name

# Add the "security" section either on the root level (if all endpoints
# are secured with this token), or inside individual GET/POST/etc. operations
security:
  - session_token: []
```

Comment: yes! it was pretty simple, I have used the first part of your answer. Thank you!